# Better way to get data from SOAP and no blocking Apache

Tags: php, apache, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a problem on a website that is getting data through SOAP. I think while waiting for the data, and other people accessing the webpage, apache can't handle all the requests while waiting that long and I am getting high response times.

I am doing the SOAP call with the regular way:

```
self::$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_url);
self::$session = self::$client->login( $wsdl_usr, $wsdl_key );

self::$client->call( self::$session, 'product.list', $args );
```

I've searched about asynchronous SOAP calls in PHP, but I don't know how I would do it, because I need that data to be shown to the user.

I have wsdl cache activated but still.

Should I use ajax calls to have the client ready with a loader while calling for the content to free Apache? How other ways of handling this could I use?

This SOAP call is made through a local IP already pointing in a private network, I thought this way the time would be much lesser.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is Apache, then tweak Apache to handle more concurrent requests and not your PHP code. Then think how to make your SOAP Service faster rather changing PHP code.